# Can I route traffic to a connected VPN based on a given hostname?

Tags: vpn, routing, traffic

The company I work for (small startup) has setup a VPN to add an extra layer of security to the services we connect to (say, for instance a Wiki). We, the employees, work from home and connect to the company VPN when we need to access the Wiki; however, once I connect, all the traffic from my computer goes through the VPN -which is annoying as the VPN connection is way slower than my the ISP provided bandwidth-. Is there a way to setup a routing rule so that traffic from my computer goes through the VPN ONLY when trying to access specific hostnames?.

My OS is: macOS Catalanina 10.15.5
As a premise, there are no changes I can make on the company firewall; but I do can change any config on my computer.

Comment: It depends on the VPN solution if this can be changed. Even if it could be changed, you would likely break your company policy by doing that.

Comment: To expand on the comment above: yes that may be possible to and might even be desirable (when allowed). Technically you do that by only routing the network addresses and network ranges used on your internal company network over your vpn connection. You may need to route specific internet destinations over the vpn as well when those are protected by IP whitelisting that relies on traffic originating from your company network. All other traffic is then routed directly by-passing the VPN.